# Mapping USB filesystems to USB ports

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb

I have a linux box with 8 usb ports (1-8), and I want to be able to know when I plug in an USB, say `sda1` into one of the USB ports, which USB port it is currently plugged into.

I can see a list of all my usb busses via `lsusb` like this:

```
#:/sys/bus$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e0f:000b VMware, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

After plugging in my first USB in a random USB port i can see the filesystem `/dev/sdb1` in mount:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/user/my_usb type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

So my question is, how can I know which USB port `sdb1` is plugged into (ports 1-8)?

Comment: You have only 2 usb ports.

Comment: Yes, that i on my machine, but I have another linux machine that has 8 ports and i want to know which `sd*1` is connected to which port.